# match first character in a regex?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

`http://([^:]*):?([0-9]*)(/.*)`

When I match that against `http://brandonhsiao.com/essays/showers.html`, the parentheses grab: `http://brandonhsiao.com/essays` and `/showers.html`. How can I get it to grab `http://brandonhsiao.com` and `/essays/showers.html`?

Comment: Why aren't you using a URL parser for this task?

Comment: As dumb as this may sound, I'm using Lisp, which I'm new to, and I don't know where to find any libraries.

Comment: By the way, are you that guy who owns whathaveyoutried.com? If so, I feel a little guilty.

Comment: No, I'm not. See how my comments are signed "Matt Ball" and http:// whathaveyoutried.com says "Matt Gemmell" really big right at the top? Different names. `;-)`

Comment: Oh, right. I just remembered the name Matt off the top of my head.

Comment: Your regex has some problems. Besides not grouping, it matches crazy ports like: `http://brandonhsiao.com:essays/showers.html` or considers query parameters as domain: `http://brandonhsiao.com?whatever=essays/showers.html`. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a question mark after the first * you have to make it non-greedy. Right now your code for matching the hostname is grabbing everything all the way up to the last `/`.

```
http://([^:]*?):?([0-9]*)(/.*)
```

But that's not even what I would recommend. Try this instead:

```
(http://[^\s/]+)([^\s?#]*)
```

`$1` should have `http://brandonhsiao.com` and `$2` should have `/essays/showers.html` and any hash or query string is ignored.

Note that this is not designed to *validate* a URL, just to divide a URL up into the portion before the path, and the path itself. For example, it would happily accept invalid characters as part of the hostname. However, it does work fine for URLs with or without paths.

P.S. I don't know exactly what you are doing with this in Lisp, so I have taken the liberty of only testing it in other PCRE-compatible environments. Usually I test my answers in the exact context where they will be used.

```
$_ = "http://brandonhsiao.com/essays/showers.html";
m|(http://[^\s/]+)([^\s?#]*)|;
print "1 = '$1' and 2 = '$2'\n";

# [j@5 ~]$ perl test2.pl
# 1 = 'http://brandonhsiao.com' and 2 = '/essays/showers.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http://([^/:]*):?([0-9]*)(/.*)
```

The first group is matching everything but `:` and now I added `/`, that's because the `[^]` operator means match everything but what's inside the group, everything else is just the same.

Hope it helped!

Comment: @MattBall Sure, hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

`http:\/\/([^:]*?)(\/.*)`

The `*?` is a non-greedy match to the first slash (the one just after .com)

See http://rubular.com/r/VmU2ghAX0k for match groups